# Calendar display wrong starting day in android?

Tags: android, calendar

I have used below library for calendar but it display firstdayofweek is Monday i want to start day with sunday.

https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View

I have changed code accordingly but it still display date accordingly monday is firstday.

```
ArrayList<Date> days = new ArrayList<>();

        // Get Calendar object instance
        Calendar calendar = (Calendar) mCalendarProperties.getCurrentDate().clone();

        // Add months to Calendar (a number of months depends on ViewPager position)
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, position);

        // Set day of month as 1
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        // Get a number of the first day of the week
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        // Count when month is beginning
        int monthBeginningCell = dayOfWeek + (dayOfWeek == 1 ? 5 : -2);

        // Subtract a number of beginning days, it will let to load a part of a previous month
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -monthBeginningCell);

        /*
        Get all days of one page (42 is a number of all possible cells in one page
        (a part of previous month, current month and a part of next month))
         */
        while (days.size() < 42) {
            days.add(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        mPageMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1;
        CalendarDayAdapter calendarDayAdapter = new CalendarDayAdapter(this, mContext,
                mCalendarProperties, days, mPageMonth);

        mCalendarGridView.setAdapter(calendarDayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
```